# Search case insensitive and replace whole word

Tags: regex, go

I need to search for specific pattern and only if its whole word or combination of few words I should replace it. I am struggling with metacharacters 
Say my search pattern is: "corp."
Should be replaced with "Corporation"
so when input: "SS Corp. Ltd" expected output is "SS Corporation Ltd"

I tried using:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    search :="corp."
    rep := "Corporation"
    sample :="SS Corp. LTd"
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(^|[^_])\b`+search+`\b([^_]|$)`)
    s2 := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, "${1}"+rep+"${2}")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. An unescaped `.` matches any char other than line break, it must be escaped. Since you are building the  pattern dynamically, use `regexp.QuoteMeta`
2. As a `\b` word boundary after `.` requires a word char, you can't expect `a\.\b` to match `a. b`. Replace the boundaries with `(^|[^\p{L}0-9_])` for the leading boundary and `([^\p{L}0-9_]|$)` for the trailing boundary.
3. At this stage, the pattern will be built like this: `` `(?i)(^|[^\p{L}0-9_])`+regexp.QuoteMeta(search)+`([^\p{L}0-9_]|$)` ``, but since both the  boundaries are consuming patterns, you will never match consecutive matches (`corp. corp.` will result in `Corporation corp.`, the second one won't be replaced). You should repeat replacing until no regex match can be found.
4. And to make the pattern case insensitive, use `(?i)` inline modifier at the pattern start.

The regex will look like

```
(?i)(^|[^\p{L}0-9_])corp\.([^\p{L}0-9_]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P1ZJrr/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `(^|[^\p{L}0-9_])` - either start of string or a char other than a  Unicode letter, ASCII digit and `_`
- `corp\.` - a `corp.` substring
- `([^\p{L}0-9_]|$)` - either a char other than a  Unicode letter, ASCII digit and `_` or end of string

See [this example demo](https://play.golang.org/p/mVgq9KLiFiY):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    search :="corp."
    rep := "Corporation"
    sample :="SS Corp. Corp. LTd"
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(^|[^\p{L}0-9_])`+regexp.QuoteMeta(search)+`([^\p{L}0-9_]|$)`)
    fmt.Println(re)
    var res = sample
    for re.MatchString(res) {
        res = ReplaceWith(res, re, "${1}"+rep+"${2}")
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}

func ReplaceWith(s string, re *regexp.Regexp, repl string) string {
    return re.ReplaceAllString(s, repl)
}
```

Result: `SS Corporation Corporation LTd`.

Comment: There is another scenario where it does not seem producing result as hoped for:

Comment: there is another scenario where result does not seem as expected. Say params are as search :="corp."
    rep := "Corporation"
    sample :="SS Corp.Corp. LTd" .  in that case I was hoping to get result as  SS Corp.Corp. LTd. But result produced is SS Corp.Corporation LTd.

Comment: @Shivani If you want to only find matches in between whitespaces use `\`(?i)(^|\s)\`+regexp.QuoteMeta(search)+\`(\s|$)\``

Comment: Awesome, this gives all the results as I hoped for. Thanks